# Privilege levels in 64bit Intel architecture

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture

I'm currently reading this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/086.pdf) and while this is probably a very basic question, I can't find an answer:

- In the Privilege Level chapter, how does the CPU know in what privilege level it's currently executing; for example, on page 14:

  > The processor also performs a switch from ring 3 to ring 0 when a hardware exception occurs while executing application code.

How does it perform this switch and how does it know in what privilege level it's currently executing?